# Как написать сортировку массив по 2-м значениям?

Tags: php

Массив с некоторым колл-во ключей. Одна из них:

```
[0]=>
array(5) {
[0]=>
string(1) "1"
[1]=>
string(8) "БПЗ 385-12 нов. 002, красный"
[2]=>
string(6) "06456"
[3]=>
string(29) "барабанщики"
[4]=>
float(0)
}
```

Сортировать нужно сначала по ключу 4, если равны, по ключу 1
Вот что я наворотил:

```
if ($a[4]>$b[4]) { return -1; }

if ($a[4]<$b[4]) { return 1; }

if ($a[4]===$b[4]) {
    if ($a[1]===$b[1]) return 0;
    return ($a[1]<$b[1]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

По 4 сортируется, но вот по 1 нет. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

Ключ 4 содержит многобайтовые строки(UTF-8). Для сравнения многобайтовых строк можно использовать [Collator](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.collator.php) из [расширения интернационализации](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.intl.php) intl

Пример использования:

```
<?php
$coll = new Collator("ru_RU");
$a = "вася";
$b = "андрей";
echo $coll->compare($a, $b); // output: 1
echo $coll->compare($b, $a); // output: -1
echo $coll->compare($a, $a); // output: 0
?>
```

Также существует вариант с предварительной транслитацией многобайтовых строк в ASCII-строку, функцией [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php) и с последующим их сравнением, функцией *strcmp()*. Но такой вариант известен как [ненадежный](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910627/php-iconv-translit-for-removing-accents-not-working-as-excepted), т.к. выдаваемый результат может отличаться из-за особенностей реализации библиотеки, которую использует [расширение iconv](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.iconv.php)

Вот мой вариант сортировки. Он сортирует по описанным Вами критериям, используя *Collator*:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    [
        "1",
        "БПЗ 385-12 нов. 002, красный",
        "06456",
        "барабанщики",
        (float)0
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "БПЗ 385-12 нов. 002, красный",
        "06456",
        "барабанщики",
        -0.8
    ],
    [
        "3",
        "9З9 185-12 нов. 102, красный",
        "1645",
        "гитаристы",
        5.4
    ],
    [
        "4",
        "1ПЗ 385-12 нов. 002, красный",
        "06456",
        "аккардионисты",
        5.4
    ],
);
$coll = new Collator("ru_RU");
usort(
    $arr,
    function ($a, $b) use ($coll) {
        if ($a[4] === $b[4]) {
            return $coll->compare($a[1], $b[1]);
        }
        return $a[4] < $b[4]? -1: 1;
    }
);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Я не хочу казаться наглым, но мне, честно сказать, надоело подгонять, перепробовал все функции
https://codesandbox.io/s/q0r46lkw4
тут весь массив. 
Условие такое:Вывести товары по убыванию релевантности, если релевантность одинаковая
сортировать по полю название в лексикографическом порядке, максимум 10 штук. 

В результате должно получиться 
26 2.2
29 2
6 1.5
21 1.5
22 1.5
5 0.8
7 0.8
2 0.8
3 0.8
4 0.8

Comment: @mr Cat я обновил свой ответ.